How to automatize the visualization of a 3D ROI on a semi-transparent brain?
I am looking for a way to script the visualization of ROI parcellations (in volume-space and provided as NIFTI-Files) on a semi-transparent brain. The outcome should like similar to the one on the picture below obtained with BrainNetViewer.
Currently, I am using BrainNetViewer for visualizing parcellations of areas of interest, such as SMA or DLPFC. However, this is cumbersome, because I am using the GUI, which doesn't seem to be maintained anymore, and it is highly time-consuming when visualizing the multiple parcellation options I have.
NIFTI File of parcellated ROI on BrainMesh_ICBM152 with BrainNetViewer

Please provide a more specific question how to ask question guide. Your question is too vague, general and/or applies only to you, it will not be searchable and useful to other users as is. My best advice: Subdivide your big project into smaller problems. What do you need? A 3D library? A way to compute a lot of data in parallel? It will help you formulate multiple, searchable, reusable questions. Hang in there and good luck on StackOverflow. It's good because it's strict.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It depends on what format you want to display information: Either volumes or meshes (the example you shared seems to be a mesh).
In any case, pyvista (and its underlying vtk library) are very powerful and usually enough for this kind of visualization.
vtk-js is also a JS library for this kind of visualizations (can be used to load pyvista/vtk scenes)
PyVista does support NIFTI files, through the underlying vtkNIFTIImageReader. See docs.pyvista.org/api/readers/_autosummary/pyvista.niftireader
For instance,
and for volume rendering: https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/02-plot/volume.html

PyVista does support NIFTI files, through the underlying vtkNIFTIImageReader.  See https://docs.pyvista.org/api/readers/_autosummary/pyvista.niftireader
